# I want grab 1 random item out of 4 different arrays and display the result

Tags: objective-c, arrays, random

I have an app that uses 3 arrays. The interface is basically 3 picker wheels that one can use to select from a plethora of choices to form a 3 part answer.

But, I need to randomize these not unlike what urban spoon does short of the graphical aspect.

I just need to implement a button that will reach into the arrays and give me a random selection from each array.

Here is a snippet of my code as it sits now...

Any help would be appreciated...

```
import "DoubleComponentPickerViewController.h"

@implementation DoubleComponentPickerViewController

@synthesize doublePicker;
@synthesize firstTypes;
@synthesize middleTypes; 
@synthesize lastTypes;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed
{
NSInteger firstRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:kfirstComponent];
NSInteger middleRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:kmiddleComponent];
NSInteger lastRow = [doublePicker selectedRowInComponent:klastComponent];
NSString *first = [firstTypes objectAtIndex:firstRow];
NSString *middle = [middleTypes objectAtIndex:middleRow];
NSString *last = [lastTypes objectAtIndex:lastRow];
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ test.",first, middle, last];
UIAlertView *alert = [[ UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Description:"
                                                 message:message
                                                delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
[message release];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
NSArray *firstArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        @"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",nil];
    self.firstTypes = firstArray;
    [firstArray release];

    NSArray *middleArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        @"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",nil];
    self.middleTypes = middleArray;
    [middleArray release];

    NSArray *lastArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
        @"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",nil];
    self.lastTypes = lastArray;
    [lastArray release];
```

Comment: Please simplify the sample code. Nobody is going to bother to read it.

Comment: Did you have a specific question about this?  Is something not working as you expected?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion...

The way things sit right now is I have 3 wheels that the user can spin and once satisfied with their selection can hit a button that will display the result. I simply want to implement an additional button that will grab 1 random item out of each array and display that string of results. I am not necessarily concerned at the moment with the spinning of the wheels, I just want to grab the random elements at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick a random element of `firstTypes` like this:

```
NSObject *randomFirst = [self.firstTypes objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(self.firstTypes.count)];
```

Comment: Odd - `arc4random_uniform()` isn't listed when I do a `man arc4random()`, but the other flavors are. I wonder why?

Comment: `arc4random_uniform` was added in Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) and iOS 4.3.  If you need to support an older OS, use `arc4random() % self.firstTypes.count` (which has a very small bias if the count is not a power of two).

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your help (and your critique of my less-than-helpful answer! That'll teach me to post before noon).